# Periodic solution of an ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

Let us consider the follwing cauchy problem:
$$\eqalign{
  & y'(t) = f(t,y(t))  \cr 
  & y(0) = 0 \cr} $$
Assume that $f$ is strictely positive function and it is globally lipschitz and it is $\tau $ periodic with respect to the first variable. In addition, assume that $y(t)\in[0,1]$ for all positive $t$.
Let $T$ be the unique positive constant such that $y(T)=1$. I have two questions:
Are the solution is $\tau$-periodic?.
Do we have $\tau$=$T$?.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $f$ is strictly positive and $y \in [0,1]$, then we get a contradiction if such a $T$ exists, since $y(T+\varepsilon) > y(T) = 1$, since it must increase strickly, but then it is not in $[0,1]$ anymore...

Comment: So we have an equality. What about the first qustion, is ithe solution is periodic?. Thanks.

Comment: No, you don't understand my point: The assumptions as you stated them are impossible. There is no such system with these conditions.

Either you remove the condition that $y(t) \in [0,1]$ holds for all $t$.
Then the system is not periodic, since it increases always, i.e. it never returns.

Or you remove the condition that $f$ is strictely positive. Here it is only reasonable to assume that $f$ can also be negative. Then it is possible that $y(t)$ is periodic, but it is unrelated to the value of $T$.

Comment: Excuse me sir, I forgot to say that the solution is defined only for $t \in[0,T]$ and we have a new ODE in each intervall of the form $[nT,(n+1)T]$ with initial condition $y(nT)=0$ and $y((n+1)T)=1$. Does this make sense now?

Comment: @Gustave: You should edit that into the question. Anyway, unless $T$ happens to be a multiple of $\tau$ (which is has no reason to be), it's pretty clear that $y$ isn't going to be period, isn't it?